# tab bar panel not showing on all views..

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My tab bar with icons at bottom of the is not showing on all views... like I will go to the following view on button tap... there the tab bar is not showing... this is my `onbuttontap` function

```
myAccFunction: function() { 
  var MyUser=Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Sample.view.Userinfo')); 
  Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(MyUser, this.getSlideLeftTransition()); 
  console.log('UserinfoAction'); },
```

tab bar is showing when I go directly to the view using icon on the tab bar.. but when I go to the view using button tap tab bar is not showing ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewport is the main view that takes usually full screen. Inside the viewport you normally have a panel with tabbars, navigation/title bar and if you want to present multiple pages there - you use `cards` layout. But the point would be - not to add these pages directly to the viewport, but rather add them to your main panel.

Comment: I understand to some extent ..can you please send me an example on how to use card layouts..?? and how to add viewport to the main..